# Why i can't center with margin:0 auto;

Tags: html, css, center, margin

Why can't I center with `margin:0 auto`?

This is my CSS and HTML code:

```css
/*Our Reset*/

/*Our Menu*/

#navMenu {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #161D39;
  opacity: 0.9;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#navMenu > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
}
#navMenu > li:hover {
  background-color: #161D39;
}
#navMenu > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 18px 25px;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
}
/*Our DropDown Menu*/

#navMenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  /**/
  z-index: -1;
  /**/
  top: -999px;
  /**/
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #161D39;
  transition: .3s;
  /**/
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  /**/
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  /**/
}
#navMenu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #161D39;
}
#navMenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  /**/
  top: 55px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navMenu">
  <li><a href="/">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/nosotros/">Acerca de</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/helpers/">Helpers</a>

    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Información</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="reglas-del-juego/">Reglas del juego</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="staff-del-juego/">Staff del juego</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sanciones/">Sanciones</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="brigada-anti-hack/">Brigada Anti Hack</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://eshelpers.com/standalones/">Standalones</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="preguntas-frecuentes/">FAQ</a>
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacto">Contactanos</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you trying to center?

Comment: `position:fixed` and `float:left` both prevent centering by `margin:0 auto`.

Comment: Your navMenu has float:left; position:fixed;

Comment: i can't understand, can u fix the css :/?

Comment: again: my english is bad to understand :(

Comment: *Specifically* which part is difficult to understand?

Comment: i don't have knowledge in css

Comment: I don't learn textual. I'm sorry and thanks Rich. Good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix position: absolute; and margin: 0 auto; on the same element if you want things to center. You'll need to either add another relatively positioned child div to house your centered element or remove absolute positioning. A good example is available in this question:

[need help CSS centering with absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034449/need-help-css-centering-with-absolute-positioning)

Further detail on why they wont mix:
http://www.sitepoint.com/css-center-position-absolute-div/

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`, and `position:relative;`

Comment: can u fix the css? please :(

Comment: where i have to use it?

Comment: Remove your position:fixed; and float:left; add in the margon-left:auto; margin-right:auto; and position:relative; to your navMenu